# Projects for Topology?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I am in a Topology course in undergraduate. We are in Chapter 2 right now of Patty's Foundations of Topology. We are supposed to do a project outside the book but I'm not feeling creative right now. Any ideas for a project, maybe an important theorem I could try to re-prove? I really don't want to have to regurgitate or do an arts and crafts project or some other trivial thing, but I can't make any ideas.

Comment: How about Furstenberg's topological proof of the infinitude of primes?

Comment: @Mathgemini that could work. I could enter into the debate of whether it is "really topological".

Comment: It isn't really, but I dare say that on the mere basis of that chapter 2 it's going to be rather hard to prove an "important theorem" in topology.. perhaps the Baire Category Theorem. I guess it's best to pick some math topic you already know and try to restate in in terms of the topological terminology in the style of the above proof or perhaps expose some exotic examples of topologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an interesting question that could be answered in a mini research project.

> Consider the collection of all subsets $A$ of the topological space $X$. The operations of closure $A\to \bar{A}$ and complementation $A\to X-A$ are functions from this collection to itself.
>
> (a) Show that starting with a given set $A$, one can form no more than 14 distinct sets by applying these two operations successively.
>
> (b) Find a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ (in its usual topology) for which the maximum of 14 is obtained.

This problem is stated in Munkres' *Topology* and is apparently due to [Kuratowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazimierz_Kuratowski).

**Added much later:** This problem has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem).

Comment: strange!!!!!!!!